# It is in the djangogirls tutorial in creating a blog

Tags: python, django

i am having problems with -r requirements in the creation of my first project
which is creating a blog.

> "  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   Django~=2.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions:
>   1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.11.10, 1.11.11, 1.11.12, 1.11.13, 1.11.14, 1.11.15, 1.11.16, 1.11.17, 1.11.18, 1.11.20) (line 1)) "

No matching distribution found for Django~=2.0.6 is the answer I am getting.

furthermore the command-line"django-admin startproject mysite ." says that the command is not found

Comment: Apparently _something_ says it can only use Django < 2, and you have 2.0.6 in your requirements.txt. You can either figure out what the problem is, or change it to 1.11.20 in the requirements.txt.

Comment: Please reformat your question because is 100% unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 2, then you won't be able to install Django 2.x. That is why you only see 1.x versions.

Refer to the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.0/#python-compatibility

Comment: If that's the problem, they should really start with Python 3.

Comment: The Django Girls tutorial does actually say that you should use Python 3: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/python_installation/

Comment: I am using python3

Comment: @B.Snowflake Can you confirm that by running `pip --version`?

Comment: pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7) ....that is what I got

Answer (score 0):

Try typing:

```
python3 --version
```

If that works, create a virtual environment with this command:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

Then try again.